# Polytonic Greek keyboard not working as described in keymap

Tags: debian, keyboard, language

On my Debian machine (using Gnome for X), I have it set up to switch between English (US) and Greek (Polytonic) for the keyboards. In the Greek keymap file (/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gr), I have the lines

```
partial alphanumeric_keys alternate_group
xkb_symbols "polytonic" {

include "gr(extended)"

name[Group1] = "Greek (polytonic)";

key.type[Group1] = "THREE_LEVEL";

key <AD11> { [ dead_tilde, dead_diaeresis, dead_macron ] }; // ~ ¨ ¯
key <AD12> { [  dead_iota,     VoidSymbol,  dead_breve ] }; // ͺ   ˘

key <AC10> { [ dead_acute, dead_psili  ] }; // ´ ̓
key <AC11> { type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL",
             [ dead_grave, dead_dasia, apostrophe, quotedbl  ] };
             // ` ̔  ' "
};
```

So I would expect when I type `AltGr + [` (I.e, `AltGr + AD11`) I would get a dead macron (`include "level3(ralt_switch)"` is part of the Greek (Extended) keyboard). But I do not get a macron, I instead just get [. What gives? Why isn't this keyboard working as described in the keymap file? (AltGr seems to work fine on the other keys, also.)